# Reading arguments from accepted scanner

Tags: java

I've been assigned the simple task of:

1) Accepting a Scanner argument and reading space-separated words from it.

2) If a word is a valid real number such as 0.1 or -3.14159 or 87 then add the number onto a running total.

3) When there is no more input available in the scanner, return total.

This is the magic that I have produced so far:

```
public static double sumReal(Scanner input) {
 while(input.hasNext()) {
}
  }
```

I understand that "hasNext" returns a boolean, but how can I confirm that it is a double and not a string?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: try creating a double from it Instead of using instanceof you can  cast to the presumed object type and listen for the ClassCastException 


try{
Double value = Double.ParseDouble("your string");
}catch (ClassCastException)
{
}

Comment: sorry java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: here is the code

[SOLVED] - How to check if a string is a double safely in JAVA
http://hongouru.blogspot.com.uy/2016/02/solved-how-to-check-if-string-is-double.html

Comment: thanks :), i'll make sure to take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the hasNextDouble() - Method will do the trick.

```
//some code
while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: What if my loop hits a value that isn't a double, like a String, will it break?

Comment: _Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value using the nextDouble() method_

so: `input.hasNextDouble()` will just return false and the loop will end the normal way

Comment: Ive edited my answer
always catch possible bad behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
while (isDouble(input.nextLine())) {
          // your code
    }
```

& add a **method** to check if a number is Double or not

```
 public static boolean isDouble(String str) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```